# Python lxml how to undo an addnext()

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

I am performing web scraping in Python using lxml. Upon finding a tag that I find useful, I mark it with the following command:

```
myelement.addnext(etree.XML("<p>"+RandomString+"</p>"))
```

where `RandomString` is random string of a fixed length. Now after performing certain analysis, I realise that this is not the tag that has to be extracted, and I wish to undo the `addnext()` command.

This is what I tried doing:

```
myelement.getparent().remove(etree.XML("<p>"+RandomString+"</p>"))
```

However, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Element is not a child of this node.
```

Simply put, how can I reverse the `addnext` command?

Please note that I want only answers that involve `lxml` and do not want any solutions suggesting me to shift to `Beautifulsoup`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, to get you there you need to undo the effect of `addnext()`. The new element added by that method is added immediately next to the original `myelement`; that's what you have to target for removal:

```
myelement.addnext(etree.XML("<p>"+RandomString+"</p>"))
target = my_element.getnext()
target.getparent().remove(target)
```